# Add blank editable row to Datagrid but not to collection/list

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

How do I go about having a blank row in the Datagrid, but it's not added to the Collection (model)?  This should be more like a placeholder row that when filled out correctly THEN gets added to the collection/model and a blank row shows up.

After research a lot of people recommended just inserting a blank object into the collection (not really what I want to do) or wrap a collection in my own wrapper class.  Is there anyway to use templates to do this?

EDIT: If anyone is familiar with GNUCash, that's what I'm going for...

## MainWindow.xaml

```html
<Window x:Class="LogbookApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LogbookApp">
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_File" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Edit" />
        </Menu>
        <ToolBar Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="toolBar1" VerticalAlignment="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        </ToolBar>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}" CanUserAddRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="Column">
           <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=ID}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

And I'm binding to a CollectionViewSource, but I've also tried it with an ObservableCollection type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED...

The class, LogbookEntry in this case, needs to have an empty constructor ie.

```
public class LogbookEntry ()
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `CanUserAddRows="True"` will give you your placeholder

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="True">
```

Comment: works for me.. can you share your datagrid xaml and the ItemsSource type you are binding to